# Cannot create an IPA file

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, share, archive

I am trying to create an IPA file to post my application on TestFlight and to share it to beta testers.

I compiled and archived my app with my AdHoc provisioning profile configured in my project and target build setting, but nothing appears in Organizer/Archives so I can't create my .ipa file.

I saw I had to create an entitlement.plist file in XCode File/New/New File and "section signing" on the left but I don't have access to "section signing", it doesn't appear.

So I don't know how I can fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Skip Install" set to YES in your build settings? If so, try NO.